# Why do I get syntax error for the expression evaluator program?

Tags: c, flex-lexer, context-free-grammar, bisonc++

I tried the following input

a = 10;

print a;

print 1+2+3;

a = 5+10;

I get syntax error when I try to execute the file with above input
There's no error during compilation

Here's the code

Flex

```
%{
/* header files */
%}

/* regex */

%option yylineno

%%


"println"       {  printf("token is println");  return(TOK_PRINTLN);}
"print" { printf("token is print"); return(TOK_PRINTLN); }

"main()" { return(TOK_MAIN); }
{digit}+    {  /* convert to int and store its val*/
              printf("token is %d", yylval.int_val);
            return INTEGER;
            }
{id} {
      /* convert to char */
      printf("token is %c", yylval.id_val);
      return(TOK_ID);
     } 

";" {   return(TOK_SEMICOLON);  }
"+" {   return(TOK_ADD);    }
"-" {   return(TOK_SUB);    } /* not req  */
"*" {   return(TOK_MUL);    }
"/" {   return(TOK_DIV);    } /* not req  */
"=" { return(TOK_EQ);   }
[ \t\n]     {printf("token is space");}

.   {printf("Invalid character '%c', ignored\n", 
        yytext[0]);
    }

%%
```

For bison, we use a symbol table which is an array.
We get the variable (identifier represented by TOK_ID) and convert it to index where we can store value of the expression.

Bison File

```
%{
  /* header file and fucn dec*/
%}


%union{
    int int_val;
    char id_val;       
      }
```

/* tokens and types */
    %start stmt

```
%right TOK_EQ
%left TOK_ADD TOK_SUB
%left TOK_MUL TOK_DIV


%%

 /* grammar */

stmt: expr_stmt TOK_SEMICOLON
     {; /* do nothing*/
     }
     | TOK_PRINTLN expr TOK_SEMICOLON 
     {
      printf("%d \n",$2);
     }
     | stmt TOK_PRINTLN expr TOK_SEMICOLON
     {
     printf("%d \n",$3);
     }
     | stmt expr TOK_SEMICOLON
     {
     ;
     }
;

expr_stmt: TOK_ID TOK_EQ expr
       {
        setSTVal($1, $3);
       }
;

expr:
   /*expr stuff */
```

;

```
%%

int getSTIndex(char c){
  /* return index*/
}

int getSTVal(char c){
  /* set val*/
}

void setSTVal(char c, int v){
   /* set table val*/
 }


 int yyerror(char *s)
{

 printf("\nsyntax error on line no %d\n",yylineno);
return 0;
 }

void initializeSymbolTable(){
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)symbol_table[i] = 0; /*avoiding garbage val*/
         /* initializn stuff */
 }

 int main()
 {
  initializeSymbolTable();
  yyparse(); /* C routine produced by lex */
  return 0;
  }
```

When I tried to debug with input a=5; and a = 5;
It could capture the token a but it threw syntax error after that
It coudnt capture = and everything after that.

I can't figure out why it captures only the first digit/command/string and then throws syntax error

Comment: The listings are incomplete (e.g. `digit` is not defined) and hence do not compile. Pease add enough "meat" to get us a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you.

Comment: so, your issue is with the lexer?  I'd make sure my lexer was working before digging into the parser

Comment: @picklerick I am not sure what to do next

Comment: your space regex is negating the space chars? I don't see that in your code

Comment: @picklerick I haven't used that in code. Plus I tried input with and without spaces and it still didn't work. I was not sure how to use the space regex

Comment: >you mean the regex part or the tokens as well? Yes, all of it, for easy c&p such that we can build it without any additional work. I don't want to add everything just to find out that I don't have any errors anymore and the error is in the parts of the code that you have omitted.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi@deamentiaemundi you mean the regex part or the tokens as well? I was a bit worried about adding everything since this is my school assignment... Here's the regex digit ([0-9]) id ([a-z][a-z0-9]*) space ([^ \t\n\r\f\v]+) . But currently, I am only testing for char ids, so basically I am expecting and using only char instead of char* for id

Comment: @deamentiaemundi ok let me do that.

Comment: This cannot be correct: `#include "calc1.tab.h"` `#include "y.tab.h"`. One of those files must be outdated. Doesn't it cause compile errors, or at least warnings? You should clean up your build directories and revise your build procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I simplify your grammar a bit to

```
/* ... */
%start input
/* ... */

input: /* empty file/no input */
     | input stmt

/* each statement is an "expr" followed by a semicolon */
stmt: expr TOK_SEMICOLON
     {
       ;
     }
     /* This is a function and should go into the rule "expr", too, btw. */
     | TOK_PRINTLN expr TOK_SEMICOLON 
     {
      printf("%d \n",$2);
     }
;


expr: /* empty expression */
    expr TOK_ADD expr
    {
    $$ = $1 + $3;
    }
    /* ... */
    | INTEGER
    {
     $$ = $1;
    };
    | TOK_ID
    {
     $$ =  getSTVal($1);
    }
    | TOK_ID TOK_EQ expr
    {
      setSTVal($1, $3);
    }
  ;
```

It works with the input file

```
a = 10;

print
   a;

print 1+2+3;

a = 5
     +
      10;
print a;
```

as expected. It is not very elegant but should point you in the right direction.

Your problem was that `TOK_ID` is in two rules and the second occurrence of `TOK_EQ` happened when the parser was in `expr` and there is no rule for `TOK_ID TOK_EQ` only for `TOK_ID` alone. (it is a bit more complicated than that, admitted)

If you have the Bison documentation at hand you might look for the `mfcalc` example.